# A YouTubePlayerView can only be created with an Activity which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as its context

Tags: java, android, xml, youtube-api

I'm getting this error is my XML file but can't figure it out as my Activity already extends YouTubeBaseActivity. Can anybody help me?

```
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

Activity:

```
public class UserHomepage extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener
```

Stack Trace

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A YouTubePlayerView can only be created with an Activity  which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as its context.
at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.<init>(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all other similar exception happened are due to not extending `YoutubeBaseActivity`. This is probably a bug, probably the layout inflater tries to instantiate the view passing `Activity` context instead `YoutubeBaseActivity`.

Take 0:

Check if you are using the latest version of sdk, tools and youtube api.

Take 1:

Put a `FrameLayout` with same attributes and later add the `YoutubePlayerView` programatically. Simple `FrameLayout` should not contribute much towards your view hierarchy. Anyways, give it a try.

Take 2: 
Use fragment version of the player.

Comment: How to Take 2 ?

Comment: take 1 not working, still giving same issue. take 2 : can't use that.

Answer (score -1):

Download `YoutubePlayer` `API` jar file from here **https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/**

and then put into libs folder and then add this line in dependencies

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
```