# YouTubePlayerSupportFragment inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube

I have a fragment and I want to play YouTube video inside fragment. For this I have follow the following steps:

1. Created project on Google console
2. Generate Key
3. Download and install YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.
4. Create a simple fragment
5. Add YouTubePlayerSupportFragment
6. Write the code  in java file

When I run App, got an error message:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A YouTubePlayerView can only be created with an Activity  which extends YouTubeBaseActivity as its context.
```

Code of XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     
    

       <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
                    android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
                    android:id="@+id/YoutubePlayer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="240dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Code of Java File

```
    public class TopicYoutubeFragment extends Fragment implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
    private YouTubePlayer youtubeplayer;
    private static final String YoutubeDeveloperKey = "AIzaSyAp8uMTh0VnYI";

    private String YoutubeURL, youtubeID;
    private String TopicName;
    private static final int RECOVERY_REQUEST = 1;

    private YouTubePlayerView ypv;

    public TopicYoutubeFragment() {

    }

    public static TopicYoutubeFragment newInstance(String YoutubeURL, String TopicName) {
        TopicYoutubeFragment fragment = new TopicYoutubeFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("YoutubeURL", YoutubeURL);
        args.putString("TopicName", TopicName);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            YoutubeURL = getArguments().getString(YoutubeURL);
            TopicName = getArguments().getString(TopicName);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.topicyoutubefragment, container, false);
        ypv = view.findViewById(R.id.YoutubePlayer);
        ypv.initialize(YoutubeDeveloperKey, this);
        youtubeID = "F7xdbsjFGtU";
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
        if (!b) {
            if (youtubeID != null)
                youTubePlayer.cueVideo(youtubeID); // Plays https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7xdbsjFGtU
            else
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Video is available for this Topic", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(getActivity(), RECOVERY_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            String error = String.format(getString(R.string.player_error), errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35002304/a-youtubeplayerview-can-only-be-created-with-an-activity-which-extends-youtubeba

Comment: @akashzincle My requirement is play YouTube video inside fragment instead of Activity.I already implement it on Activity but facing problem with fragment

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63081774/7967235) worked for me