# How to instantiate YoutubePlayerView in an android fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-youtube-api

I am creating an app which will load videos from youtube. The problem I am having is that i can not figure out how to instantiate a YoutubePlayerView inside an android fragment since my app only has one activity and all of the UI stuff is managed through fragments and navigation graph.

The only thing that i could figure out is instantiating YoutubePlayerView inside a YoutubeBaseActivity which will compromise the consistency of navigation since it will be a new activity.
I tried creating a YoutubePlayerFragment but it can't be set as a destination in a navigation graph.
So I will be thankful if anyone can help me figure out how to do this. :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Owais! Staying at the docs [https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView] `YoutubePlayerView` can only be instantiated within a `YoutubeBaseActivity`, so if you want to only use fragments for navigating that's probably not a viable solution here. `YoutubePlayerFragment` seems to meet all of your requirements, why exactly can't it be used in a navigation graph? It extends `Fragment`, so it should actually behave like any other fragment for what concerns navigation :)

Comment: Hey Marino, You are right that youtubePlayer fragment should behave like any other fragment since it extends the fragment, but when i try to add it as a destination in graphical editor of navigation graph, it is not identified as a fragment.

Comment: Just to help framing the issue better, could you try to create a `VideoFragment` that extends `YouTubePlayerFragment` and add it as a destination in the nav graph instead of using YouTube's one directly?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having this issue today, this is what I did and it works perfectly for Activity and Fragment.

**1. PLACE A FRAMELAYOUT**

In your Activity or Fragment XML, place a `FrameLayout`. Simple enough.

```
   <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_player"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"/>
```

**2. INSTANTIATE YoutubePlayerSupportFragment AND ADD IT TO THE FRAME LAYOUT**

Type in the next lines and if you get an error regarding the use of android.support.v4.Fragment you're going to have to create a new custom class of YoutubePlayerSupportFragment. I think this error happens because the YoutubePlayerSupportFragment class extends from android.support.v4.Fragment and I'm using androidx, I'm not sure. Still, I'm doing this inside a click listener, but you can do it anywhere else like in `onViewCreated()` or in `onCreateView()`

```
   val youtubePlayerSupportFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance()
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.main_player, youtubePlayerSupportFragment).commit()
   // these lines of code populates the FrameLayout with a brand new YoutubePlayerSupportFragment
   // this code is actually for an Activity. If you want to do it for a fragment, replace the `supportFragmentManager` for `childFragmentManager` and it should work as well. It does for me.
```

So if these lines of code give you error, you have create a new class in **this exact new path** `com.google.android.youtube.player` and inside this directory create a new class. You can call it whatever you want. Just copy and paste this:

```
package com.google.android.youtube.player //<--- IMPORTANT!!!!

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.ab
import java.util.*

class YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX : Fragment(), YouTubePlayer.Provider {
    private val a = ViewBundle()
    private var b: Bundle? = null
    private var c: YouTubePlayerView? = null
    private var d: String? = null
    private var e: YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener? = null
    override fun initialize(var1: String, var2: YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener) {
    d = ab.a(var1, "Developer key cannot be null or empty")
    e = var2
    a()
}

private fun a() {
    if (c != null && e != null) {
        c?.a(this.activity, this, d, e, b)
        b = null
        e = null
    }
}

override fun onCreate(var1: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(var1)
    b = var1?.getBundle("YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.KEY_PLAYER_VIEW_STATE")
}

override fun onCreateView(var1: LayoutInflater, var2: ViewGroup?, var3: Bundle?): android.view.View? {
    c = YouTubePlayerView(Objects.requireNonNull(this.activity), null, 0, a)
    a()
    return c
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    c?.a()
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    c?.b()
}

override fun onPause() {
    c?.c()
    super.onPause()
}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(var1: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(var1)
    (if (c != null) c?.e() else b)?.let { var2 ->
        var1.putBundle("YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.KEY_PLAYER_VIEW_STATE", var2)
    }
}

override fun onStop() {
    c?.d()
    super.onStop()
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    this.activity?.let { c?.c(it.isFinishing)  }
    c = null
    super.onDestroyView()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    if (c != null) {
        val var1 = this.activity
        c?.b(var1 == null || var1.isFinishing)
    }
    super.onDestroy()
}

private inner class ViewBundle : YouTubePlayerView.b {
    override fun a(var1: YouTubePlayerView, var2: String, var3: YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener) {
        e?.let { initialize(var2, it) }
    }

    override fun a(var1: YouTubePlayerView) {}
}

companion object {
    fun newInstance(): YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX {
        return YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX()
    }
}
}
```

Line 36 is going to stay with a red underline but just dont pay atention to it. Couldn't find a way to solve it but it works fine.

In my case, I'm using my custom class so the lines of code I typed above turn out to be very similar:

```
   val youtubePlayerSupportFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX.newInstance() //notice this is my custom class, it ends with an X
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.main_player, youtubePlayerSupportFragment).commit()
```

**3. INITIALIZE YOUTUBE PLAYER SUPPORT FRAGMENT**

Now you should have your YoutubePlayerSupportFragment ready to go.

After being sure this works, you have to **initialize** the youtubePlayer. You have to do that just by calling `youtubePlayerSupportFragment.initialize(apiKey, listener)`. Inside the parenthesis you have to set your apiKey and a listener. The api key can be generated easily, just google it if you don't have one. And for the listener you can do `ctrl + shift + spacebar` to open the smart suggestions, and it should pop up first. In my case it looks something like this:

```
val youtubePlayerSupportFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragmentX.newInstance() 
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.main_player, youtubePlayerSupportFragment).commit()

youtubePlayerSupportFragment.initialize(
                    resources.getString(R.string.API_KEY), //IF YOU HAVE NO API KEY IT WONT WORK. But that's actually explained in the docs. So you can google it easily if you don't have one
                    object : YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
                        override fun onInitializationSuccess(
                            p0: YouTubePlayer.Provider?,
                            p1: YouTubePlayer?,
                            p2: Boolean
                        ) {
                            p1?.loadVideo("9ET6R_MR1Ag") // string has to be https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=----------->9ET6R_MR1Ag<---------
                        }

                        override fun onInitializationFailure(
                            p0: YouTubePlayer.Provider?,
                            p1: YouTubeInitializationResult?
                        ) {
                            layoutUtils.createToast(
                                applicationContext,
                                "ERROR INITIATING YOUTUBE"
                            )
                        }
                    })
```

And that's it! Lot of work, yeah, but it's worth it. It works perfectly even though the api documentation is poorly written and it has some bugs. But to the user looks exactly like youtube so it's going to give your app a very professional look. At least that's the feedback I got when I implemented it.

**Important note:**

If you want to play a video, and let the user be able to play other videos on cue, like on a click just like youtube, you have to store the youtubePlayer in a variable the moment it is initialized. For example:

```
var youtubePlayer: YoutubePlayer? = null // this is a global variable of your class
```

And when the player is successfully initiated, store it like this:

```
override fun onInitializationSuccess(
                            p0: YouTubePlayer.Provider?,
                            p1: YouTubePlayer?,
                            p2: Boolean
                        ) {
                            p1?.loadVideo(video)
                            youtubePlayer = p1 // <------- this line here
                        }
```

Then in any part of your code you can just do `youtubePlayer.loadVideo(anotherLink)` and it will automatically stop the current video and start playing the new one.